# Dockefile ADD Command - Add entire directory to container desitination

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

My folder structure:

App

- project
- bindmount
- docker-compose.yml

My 'project' folder contains a folder "code" and Dockerfile

My **Docker Compose** file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    build: ./project
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./bindmount:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

The **Dockerfile** in the 'project' folder is fairly simple

```
FROM wordpress

#Copy code to container
ADD ./code /var/www/html/code
```

---

The ADD command dosen't seem to be working when I look into the 'bindmount' folder (cannot find the 'code' folder).

COPY, mkdir also don't seem to work.

I'm able to achieve this when the destination url is anything other than "/var/www/html"

Comment: try replacing ADD with COPY

Comment: tried, dosen't work

Comment: ADD/COPY in Dockerfile is overwritten with volumes that is mentioned in docker-compose.yml , For the moment try removing `volume` from docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

try this tip:
add / end of ADD command. like this:
ADD ./code/ /var/www/html/code/